# ri output can't be piped into less

Tags: ruby, unix, rdoc, ri

I'm running ri version 2.5.8 and ruby 1.9.2. If I try something like `ri Enumerable | less`, the paging is broken in less. I see output but I can't use CTRL-F or CTRL-B to page back and forward. If I try to, I just see the literal "^F" and "^B" characters output at the bottom of the screen. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ri -T String | less`.

If you want that behavior always you could put `alias ri='ri -T'` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`, which ever you use.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't change the behavior I described. Maybe something is wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try `PAGER=/usr/bin/less ri Enumerable` - specifying pager in environment variables did the trick for me.

For a permanent solution do something like `echo "export PAGER=/usr/bin/less" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the problem on OSX 10.6 terminal and iTerm2 with ri version 2.5.8 and ruby 1.9.2. Did anyone find a fix? At the moment I can use the scrollbar of my graphical terminal client, but it gets tedious.

As a workaround I use the ORI gem, ri from within irb: https://github.com/dadooda/ori

Comment: when you want to be updated about this dont post an answer to this question. fav it instead or write a comment.